# Can we increase the contrast on the top users score values

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

Apologies if this question has already been asked or discussed, I personally am not too bothered by most of the changes but agree that they could be improved but this one got me. If you view the [Top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers) for a particular tag then the contrast is very poor for the score value next to the number of answers posted value:
[image: Tag scores]

This is barely readable on my laptop (due to the poor viewing angles on LCD screens) but it means I have to readjust my screen in order to be able to view this information which was more readable before.

I am viewing the site using chrome (version 39.0.2171.99 m) on Windows 7, it also looks just as bad running firefox (version 35.0)

It is also not so readable (but not as bad as my laptop) using an ipad mini 2 running chrome and safari.

So I've now noticed that this looks poor on a Nexus 4 mobile phone using Chrome and also on a LCD monitor running Firefox or chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Eurgh, that is pretty bad. Side note, I didn't realize the tag leaderboards were redesigned as well, but I can't say I'm surprised knowing now. I find it interesting, to say the least, that they made the important numbers much smaller in size. But you can see that [it still doesn't help with users with very large badge counts](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers)...

Comment: @BoltClock that looks even worse, I can now confirm this looks poor on chrome on Nexus 4 so I think this is a general issue, hope it is looked at along with the other issues

Comment: Almost all typography on SO has lost contrast and is far too bright now (my opinion).

Comment: @DanFromGermany I agree, the numbers actually disappeared from view on my laptop until I tilted my screen

Comment: Designers and graphics professionals tend to have amazing displays and forget just how bad most people's crummy LCD screens are - I have this problem designing application UI sometimes.  Looks great for me but a quick hallway test is usually enough to discover a monstrous abyss of cheap monitors has devoured half the gamut I thought I had to work with...

Comment: @J... lets not forget advertisers and marketing departments that decide on funky colour schemes that [attack the eyes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juFZh92MUOY) and don't understand the concept of web safe colours but that is an aside I think this and other issues can be addressed because it was fine before

Comment: @EdChum I apologize for the OT comment, but is there still a need for web safe colors? Perhaps we're using different definitions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Web-safe_colors

Comment: @MarkRansom the example I recall was an ad that was designed for web use was then reused for a tv spot I think which is different as TV broadcast use Rec 601 or Rec 709 YUV colour space, also I think this was many years ago so yes it's probably not relevant in today's world but it's a minor rant about pointless colour choices but I'm probably [wrong](http://www.vcarrer.com/2010/03/about-80-million-dollars-blue-0044cc.html)

Comment: [Web accessibility RE: Contrast ratios](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html) should also be a major concern with a design.

Comment: Hey, they did revert the typography changes, did they? Looks better now, the red coloring is more intense and the contrast is back to a nice level! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The score should be a lot darker now. The change will be on live after our next production build.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll post feedback once I see the update.

Comment: OK it's better, I liked the idea of the votes and question counts being different colours but it needed better contrast, now the two counts are the same contrast and colour